# What is the best way to make a Windows service ask the user for input?

Tags: windows-services, user-input, createprocess

I'm trying to write a program to ask me to input some information periodically, so I've written a service in C to run in the background, I can watch it reporting its okay by refreshing its log file. Now I'm stuck on how to get it to open up cmd and ask for the information.

I'd like to save this information to a log file. (I'm planning on monitoring my sleeping habits)

I tried using `system("getinput.exe")` and that seems to do nothing, I know using `system()` is bad but it was a first step.

`CreateProcess()` I simply cannot get to work, the example on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682512.aspx doesn't work for me, i just get `CreateProcess failed (2)` whenever i try `createprocess.exe dir` for example.

Surely there must be a way?

EDIT: Thanks for the replies I will try to take a different approach then. Where would I start with writing a background application that can occasionally ask for user input in C?

Comment: short answer: don't. The difference bewteen an application and a service is that a service  has no UI...

Comment: http://arcanecode.com/2007/05/30/windows-services-in-c-sending-commands-to-your-windows-service-part-7/

Comment: Services are not meant to do input. Use a different kind of application to do I/O.

Comment: Services run in a different desktop than the logged in user starting with Vista, and have no access to the UI. You should re-think your approach; this is not the proper use of a service.

Comment: Thanks for the replies I will try to take a different approach then. Where would I start with writing a background application that can occasionally ask for user input in C?